# F# type instance ident bug in WCF enviroment?

Tags: wcf, f#

When it use with type instance ident and direct property members in F# coding,  run it in WCF host, and call it from client, the errors occured as below

System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:....  Please see InnerException for more details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The initialization of an object or 
value resulted in an object or value being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized

```
[<DataContract>]
type A()=
  [<DefaultValue>] val mutable _Column:DateTime
  [<DataMember>]
  member x.Column
    with get ()=x._Column
    and set v=x._Column<-v

//===============================================
//***1.***
//It's wrong with type instance ident and direct property members
//Use without 'DefaultValue'
[<Sealed>]
[<DataContract>]
type B=
  inherit A
  val mutable _ColumnA:DateTime   
  new ()={inherit A();_ColumnA=DateTime.Now}
  new (para) as x=new B() then  //Type instance ident is 'x'
    do
      x.Initialize () 

  member x.Initialize ()= 
    "TODO" |>ignore

  [<DataMember>]      //the type have direct property members
  member x.ColumnA
    with get ()=x._ColumnA
    and set v=x._ColumnA<-v   //The error will occurs  in this position, 'The initialization of an object or value resulted in an object or value being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized'

//===============================================
//***2.***
(*
//It's wrong with type instance ident and direct property members
//Use with 'DefaultValue'
[<Sealed>]
[<DataContract>]
type B=
  inherit A
  new ()={inherit A()}
  new (para) as x=new B() then  //Type instance ident is 'x'
    do
      x.Initialize () 
      x.ColumnA<-DateTime.Now

  member x.Initialize ()= 
    "TODO" |>ignore

  [<DefaultValue>] val mutable _ColumnA:DateTime   //Use with 'DefaultValue' 
  [<DataMember>]      //the type have direct property members
  member x.ColumnA
    with get ()=x._ColumnA
    and set v=x._ColumnA<-v   //The error will occurs  in this position, 'The initialization of an object or value resulted in an object or value being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized'
*)

//===============================================
//***3.***
(*
//It's right with type instance ident and without direct property members
[<Sealed>]
[<DataContract>]
type B=
  inherit A
  new ()={inherit A()}
  new (para) as x=new B() then  //Type instance ident is 'x'
    do
      x.Initialize () 

  member x.Initialize ()= 
    "TODO" |>ignore

*)

//===============================================
//***4.***
(*
// it's right when it's without type instance ident！
[<Sealed>]
[<DataContract>]
type B=
  inherit A
  new ()={inherit A()}
  new (para)=new B() then
    do
      "TODO" |>ignore
*)
```

Many thanks to Brian's reviewing and modification.

How can I correct this?

```
//------------------------------------------------------------
Addition,

namespace NS
open System

open System.ServiceModel
[<ServiceContract>]
type IService =
  [<OperationContract>] abstract Query:isAsceding:bool->B[] //The parameter name 'isAsceding' is needed in WCF enviroment


namespace NS
open System
open System.ServiceModel
[<ServiceBehavior(Name="NS.Service",InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single) >]
type Service() =
  interface IService with
    member x.Query isAsceding=
      //TODO 


<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="Shared_wsHttpBinding"
                     closeTimeout="00:02:00"
                     openTimeout="00:02:00"
                     receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                     sendTimeout="00:02:00"
                     bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                     transactionFlow="false"
                     hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="52428800"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600"
                     messageEncoding="Text"
                     textEncoding="utf-8"
                     useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                     allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="3200"
                              maxStringContentLength="819200"
                              maxArrayLength="1638400"
                              maxBytesPerRead="409600"
                              maxNameTableCharCount="1638400" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true"
                                 inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                                 enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"
                               proxyCredentialType="None"
                               realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows"
                             negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                             algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/Service"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="Shared_wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="NS.IService"
                  name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: The issue has been fixed by microsoft, so the next version will do right thing, please see [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/674139/fsharp-type-indent-bug-in-wcf-enviroment#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been fixed by microsoft, so the next version will do right thing, please see [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/674139/fsharp-type-indent-bug-in-wcf-enviroment#)